# iisClientCertificateMappingAuthentication and WCF

Tags: wcf, iis, client-certificates

I have a working WCF Service, that does what it should do, hosted by an IIS.

Now in another environment, this service shall be used as ever, but IIS should additionally require a client certificate for allowing to access.

So I generated some certificates, used iisClientCertificateMappingAuthentication to configure them and map them to users. So I can control which users can access the website and I see to what user the certificates are mapped in the FailedReqLogFiles.

Then I added a sub directory, put the WCF application in there, converted to an application with an apppool and ther the pain began.

The WCF Service is determined to demand that 'Anonymous authentication' must be activated. When I activate anonymous authenticaiton, the service can be invoked, but from then on, it doesn't matter which certificate is used for authentication.

I googled tons of articles and tried lots of configurations, but didn't success so far. I must admit, I'm not very familiar with WCF, this always drove me crazy. I do simply not understand why an application deals with the way the Webserver handles security (it's smiliar to adding SSL, when WCF is not configured properly, IIS shows 404, that's also one thing i do not understand, why the WCF is interfering with the way IIS exposes content to the world...).

Hope there's someone who could give advice, thank you very much in advance.

Regards, Chris

Answer (score 0):

You could try below setting in iis to resolve the issue:

1)Open iis manager, select your site.

2)select the SSL setting from the middle pane.

[image]

3)in SSL setting check require SSL, client certificate select accept radio button.

[image]

4)click on apply and restart iis.

You could refer the below link for how to set iisclientcertificate authentication with WCF:

- [WCF Service Using Client Certificates Requires Anonymous Access in IIS and Therefore Doesn't Actually Work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9388469/wcf-service-using-client-certificates-requires-anonymous-access-in-iis-and-there)
- [How do I implement Client Certificate authentication the right way?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14407666/how-do-i-implement-client-certificate-authentication-the-right-way)
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.webServer/security/authentication/iisClientCertificateMappingAuthentication/

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, most of the articles I already knew, but I will try the hint with the Accept option (altough I think together with anonymous auth. this is even less secure, but all these things behave not as I would expect, so i'll give it a try).